# Conversion from ___attribute___((shared)) to addrspace(3) in Clang compiler when compiling CUDA files

Tags: cuda, clang, llvm, llvm-ir, gpu-shared-memory

The clang compiler includes CUDA header file host_defines.h in which the `__shared__` is defined as `__attribute__((shared))`. When CUDA source files are compiled to internal representation (IR) using clang, the `__shared__` gets converted to `addrspace(3)`. These address spaces can be observed in the clang file [llvm/tools/clang/lib/Basic/Targets.cpp](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/Targets_8cpp_source.html) line number 1601 as an array

```
static const unsigned NVPTXAddrSpaceMap[] = {
    1, // opencl_global
    3, // opencl_local
    4, // opencl_constant
    // FIXME: generic has to be added to the target
    0, // opencl_generic
    1, // cuda_device
    4, // cuda_constant
    3, // cuda_shared
};
```

So the specific question is at which stage of conversion, the `__attribute__((shared))` gets converted as `addrspace(3)`. Looking at the parsing and lexing parts of clang gave no intimation about this. Can somebody please help ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `shared` attribute is defined in clang's `Attr.td` file and is called `CUDAShared` and represented as `CUDASharedAttr` internally. 
Lexing and parsing is done for all Attributes defined in Attr.td during the lexing and parsing stage for any Attrbiute. At this stage you won't find any necessary insights.

The first point where you will see valuable code for `CUDASharedAttr` is located in `clang/lib/Sema/SemaDeclAttr.cpp`. The Sema class builds the AST and in `SemaDeclAttr.cpp` the handling for each Attribute is done. 
For the particular `CUDASharedAttr` `handleSimpleAttribute<CUDASharedAttr>(S, D, Attr);` is called. This function just inserts the Attribute to a given declaration (`Decl& D`).

Now that the Attribute is attached to a Decl you can query if the declaration has the attribute using: `D.hasAttr<CUDASharedAttr>()`. This for example in `SemaDecl.cpp` where the limitations on CUDA shared memory declarations are enforced and the storage class of the shared memory variable is set to static.

You will again find CUDASharedAttr bin `clang/lib/CodeGen/CodeGenModule.cpp` where the actual LLVM IR is emitted. 
In CodeGenModule.cpp you have the following function:

```
unsigned CodeGenModule::GetGlobalVarAddressSpace(const VarDecl *D,
                                                 unsigned AddrSpace) {
  if (LangOpts.CUDA && LangOpts.CUDAIsDevice) {
    if (D->hasAttr<CUDAConstantAttr>())
      AddrSpace = getContext().getTargetAddressSpace(LangAS::cuda_constant);
    else if (D->hasAttr<CUDASharedAttr>())
      AddrSpace = getContext().getTargetAddressSpace(LangAS::cuda_shared);
    else
      AddrSpace = getContext().getTargetAddressSpace(LangAS::cuda_device);
  }

  return AddrSpace;
}
```

The function querys the address space for a shared function from the actual target, i.e. for the nvptx targets the address space map you posted is used:

```
static const unsigned NVPTXAddrSpaceMap[] = {
    1, // opencl_global
    3, // opencl_local
    4, // opencl_constant
    // FIXME: generic has to be added to the target
    0, // opencl_generic
    1, // cuda_device
    4, // cuda_constant
    3, // cuda_shared
};
```

`LangAS::cuda_shared` corresponds to address space 3.

After all these steps you will get a global variable in with address space 3 in your final IR module like this:

```
 ; ModuleID = 'sm.cu'
  target datalayout = "e-p:64:64:64-i1:8:8-i8:8:8-i16:16:16-i32:32:32-i64:64:64-f32:32:32-f64:64:64-v16:16:16-v32:32:32-v64:64:64-v128:128:128-n16:32:64"
  target triple = "nvptx64-unknown-unknown"

  @vec= internal unnamed_addr addrspace(3) global [32 x i32] zeroinitializer, align 4

  ; Function Attrs: nounwind readnone
  declare i32 @llvm.nvvm.read.ptx.sreg.tid.x() #0

  ; Function Attrs: nounwind readnone
  declare i32 @llvm.nvvm.read.ptx.sreg.tid.y() #0

  define ptx_kernel void @__pacxx_kernel0(i32 addrspace(1)* %tmp) {
    %1 = tail call spir_func i32 @llvm.nvvm.read.ptx.sreg.tid.x() #1
    %2 = zext i32 %1 to i64
    %3 = getelementptr i32, i32 addrspace(1)* %tmp, i64 %2
    %4 = load i32, i32 addrspace(1)* %3, align 4
    %5 = getelementptr [32 x i32], [32 x i32] addrspace(3)* @vec, i64 0, i64 %2
    store i32 %4, i32 addrspace(3)* %5, align 4
    %6 = tail call spir_func i32 @llvm.nvvm.read.ptx.sreg.tid.y() #1
    %7 = zext i32 %6 to i64
    %8 = getelementptr [32 x i32], [32 x i32] addrspace(3)* @vec, i64 0, i64 %7
    %9 = load i32, i32 addrspace(3)* %8, align 4
    %10 = getelementptr i32, i32 addrspace(1)* %tmp, i64 %7
    store i32 %9, i32 addrspace(1)* %10, align 4
    ret void
  }
```

Comment: To add support for a new memory type "\__noc__" in CUDA which is similar to "\__shared__", I modified the required clang and llvm files. From the answer I understood the program flow and added #define \__noc__ \__attribute__((noc)) in the /llvm/tools/clang/lib/Headers/\__clang_cuda_runtime_wrapper.h where the host_defines are getting included to clang. When I compile llvm with this and install, the generated IR files are not having certain fields such as "Function Attrs: uwtable". When clang is used without #define for \__noc__, this problem is not there. Any intuitions will be greatly helpful

Comment: uwtable usually comes from exception handling. It is hard to diagnose without code.

Comment: The steps in the answer was followed and it seems the clang compiler ignores the new memory type added. For a better insight the question is added in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35519825/adding-support-for-a-memory-type-similar-to-shared-in-cuda-using-clang-llvm