# Adding support for a memory type similar to __shared__ in CUDA using clang-llvm compiler

Tags: cuda, clang, llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I am working towards adding a new memory type similar to `__shared__` in CUDA called `__noc__` which needs to be compiled using clang-llvm. Following are the steps followed to achieve the parsing for the new memory type taking reference from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35356840/conversion-from-attribute-shared-to-addrspace3-in-clang-compiler-when):

**Step 1**: In the clangs's Attr.td file (clang/include/clang/Basic/Attr.td), the noc keyword was added similar to shared keyword.

```
def CUDAShared : InheritableAttr {
  let Spellings = [GNU<"shared">];
  let Subjects = SubjectList<[Var]>;
  let LangOpts = [CUDA];
  let Documentation = [Undocumented];
}

def CUDANoc : InheritableAttr {
  let Spellings = [Keyword<"noc">];
  let Subjects = SubjectList<[Var]>;
  let LangOpts = [CUDA];
  let Documentation = [Undocumented];
}
```

**Step 2**: Similar to `CUDASharedAttr`, `CUDANocAttr` was added in clang/lib/Sema/SemaDeclAttr.cpp.

```
  case AttributeList::AT_CUDAShared:
    handleSimpleAttribute<CUDASharedAttr>(S, D, Attr);
    break;
  case AttributeList::AT_CUDANoc:
    handleSimpleAttribute<CUDANocAttr>(S, D, Attr);
    printf("\n T1:SemaDeclAttr.cpp"); //testpoint 1 : for noc debugging
    break;
```

**Step 3**: In the SemaDecl.cpp file, the `CUDANocAttr` is added to enforce noc to be a static storage (similar to shared)

```
  if (getLangOpts().CUDA) {
    if (EmitTLSUnsupportedError && DeclAttrsMatchCUDAMode(getLangOpts(), NewVD))
      Diag(D.getDeclSpec().getThreadStorageClassSpecLoc(),
           diag::err_thread_unsupported);
    // CUDA B.2.5: "__shared__ and __constant__ variables have implied static
    // storage [duration]."
    if (SC == SC_None && S->getFnParent() != nullptr &&
        (NewVD->hasAttr<CUDASharedAttr>() ||
         NewVD->hasAttr<CUDANocAttr>()||
         NewVD->hasAttr<CUDAConstantAttr>())) {
      NewVD->setStorageClass(SC_Static);
    }
  }
```

**Step 4**: NOC is added in CodeGenModule (llvm/tools/clang/lib/CodeGen/CodeGenModule.cpp) to allow the access of `cuda_noc` address space from `NVPTXAddrSpaceMap`

```
    else if (D->hasAttr<CUDASharedAttr>())
      AddrSpace = getContext().getTargetAddressSpace(LangAS::cuda_shared);
    else if (D->hasAttr<CUDANocAttr>())
      AddrSpace = getContext().getTargetAddressSpace(LangAS::cuda_noc);
    else
      AddrSpace = getContext().getTargetAddressSpace(LangAS::cuda_device);
  }

  return AddrSpace;
}
```

**Step 5**: The `cuda_noc` is added to `NVPTXAddrSpaceMap` array to allow a new type of address space

```
static const unsigned NVPTXAddrSpaceMap[] = {
    1, // opencl_global
    3, // opencl_local
    4, // opencl_constant
    // FIXME: generic has to be added to the target
    0, // opencl_generic
    1, // cuda_device
    4, // cuda_constant
    3, // cuda_shared
    6, // cuda_noc
};
```

**Step 6**: The macro `#define __noc__ __location__(noc)` is added to the file clang/lib/Headers/__clang_cuda_runtime_wrapper.h where host_defines.h from CUDA is included.

The llvm source code got compiled and installed successfully. But when trying to compile a CUDA source file with the a memory type __noc__, it give the following warning:

```
warning: unknown attribute 'noc' ignored [-Wunknown-attributes]
        __noc__ int c_shared[5];
        ^

/usr/local/bin/../lib/clang/3.8.0/include/__clang_cuda_runtime_wrapper.h:69:30: note: expanded from macro '__noc__'
#define __noc__ __location__(noc)
                             ^
1 warning generated.
```

From the warnings it can be observed that `__noc__` is ignored. In the IR generated, `addrspace(6)` which is corresponding to `__noc__` is not observed.

From the debug printf put into the file clang/lib/Sema/SemaDeclAttr.cpp (step 2), it can be observed that the case for `AttributeList::AT_CUDANoc` is not getting executed.

Any suggestions or intuitions can greatly help. Is there any script to be run explicitly before compiling the llvm source code for the inputs in the *.td file to appear as C++ source code...

Comment: Are you compiling your source code with -std=cuda and are you compiling a .cu file?

Comment: Yes, I am compiling a cuda file (.cu). But didn't use -std=cuda. Now tried adding -std=cuda but even then didn't find any change. The command used for compilation is : 'sudo clang++ -emit-llvm -S -std=cuda -o noc05 -I/home/ginu001/NVIDIA_CUDA-7.5_Samples/common/inc -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64/stubs noc.cu -lcudart_static -lcuda -ldl -lrt -pthread'

Comment: Are you sure using `Keyword` spelling is correct? Does it work if you declare your array as `noc int c_shared[5]` (no `__location__`)? I think for it to work with `__location__` (which is just a macro for `__attribute__` with one less pair of parens), you should use `GNU` spelling.

Comment: I give a try with even changing `__noc__` as just `noc` (`noc int c_shared[5]`). Now it gave the error:                               `noc.cu:9:9: error: expected expression
            noc int c_shared[5];`
`            ^`

Comment: @GinuJacob Ok (not sure what `Keyword` does then), but please try with `let Spellings = [GNU<"noc">];` and rebuilding

Comment: @IsmailBadawi This is already done as specified in step 1.

Comment: @GinuJacob I don't understand? In step 1 you have `Keyword<"noc">`.

Comment: @IsmailBadawi I think you catch it right. This was a typo and was overlooked every time when reviewed.

Comment: @IsmailBadawi That was the exact reason. It worked...

Comment: Please consider writing an answer to get the question of the unanswered list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__location__(noc)` gets expanded to `__attribute__((noc))`. This is the GNU or gcc attribute syntax. So the issue is with this line:

```
let Spellings = [Keyword<"noc">];
```

In order for `noc` to work with `__location__` macro, you should use `GNU<"noc">` instead of `Keyword<"noc">`.